# ¿Cómo comparar elementos de un objeto mediante ArrayList?

Tags: java, array, poo, arraylist

A dos objetos le agregue datos que tengo que compararlos y si son iguales crear una lista nueva donde arroje los datos que son iguales, y si dos datos no son iguales, es decir si un dato de la lista A no esta en la lista B, agregarlo a la nueva lista con un "-" y si un dato de la lista B no esta en la lista A, se agrega con un "+".

Esta es mi clase principal:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListaConcepto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         ArrayList<Lista> lstA = new ArrayList<Lista>();
         ArrayList<Lista> lstB = new ArrayList<Lista>();
         ArrayList<Lista> lstC = new ArrayList<Lista>();

        Lista ObjPintura = new Lista("Hola", "Testing", "Navidad", 25.25, "Kyrie", "mua", 25);
        Lista ObjPintura2 = new Lista("Hola", "Testing", "halloween", 32.25, "Elienai", "kuaa", 25);

        lstA.add(ObjPintura);
        lstB.add(ObjPintura2);

        for(Lista e: lstA) {
             if(!e.equals("")){
                    if(lstB.contains(e)){
                        lstC.add(e);
                        //Si no, los agrega pero con "-"
                    }else{
                        lstC.add(e);
                    }

                }
        }

        for (Lista f : lstB){
            if(!f.equals(" ")){
                if(!lstA.contains(f)){
                    lstC.add(f);
                }
            }
       }

           for (Lista Resultado: lstC){
                System.out.print(Resultado+" ");

           }
    }
}
```

Creo que no estoy haciendo bien mis `equals` porque las dejo entre comillas `" "` y lo que pretendo es que vea si es igual el elemento de mis objetos.

Cómo podría solucionar ese detalle?

Mi clase Lista:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Lista {
    private String posicion;
    private String numeroParte;
    private String descripcion;
    private double monto;
    private String cambioPrecio;
    private String concepto;
    private double montoConvenio;

    public ArrayList<Lista> ListaConceptos = new ArrayList<Lista>();  

    public Lista(String posicion, String numeroParte, String descripcion, double monto, String cambioPrecio, String concepto, double montoConvenio){

        this.posicion = posicion;
        this.numeroParte = numeroParte;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.monto = monto;
        this.cambioPrecio = cambioPrecio;
        this.concepto = concepto;
        this.montoConvenio = montoConvenio;

    }


    public String getPosicion() {
        return posicion;
    }

    public String getNumeroParte() {
        return numeroParte;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public double getMonto() {
        return monto;
    }

    public String getCambioPrecio() {
        return cambioPrecio;
    }

    public String getConcepto() {
        return concepto;
    }

    public double getMontoConvenio() {
        return montoConvenio;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tenés errores conceptuales y los nombres de las variables y tipos de datos confunden mucho. Porqué la variable se llama objetoPintura y el tipo de dato es Lista. Me parece que lo que definiste como Lista debería ser Pintura o algo así. Y el ArrayList, debería ser ArrayList<Pintura>. Si podés revisar y modificar esto útlimo trato de darte una mano. De otra forma solo voy a confundirte más con una respuesta que parecerá un trabalenguas. Por otro lado los tipos de datos por convención comienzan con Mayúsculas y las variables con minúscula (objetoPintura en lugar de ObjetoPintura).

Comment: Los valores que estás tratando de comparar entre listas, no deben estar en toda la lista o solamente en la misma posición que la de referencia.                                                                                  ¿Al final los resultados van a estar en una misma lista como un tipo Objeto Lista?  Es decir, que los valores diferentes se agregan a la lista en su posición correspondiente pero con un signo de diferencia

Comment: Así es @AngelManuelElias al final se lanza un solo resultado en una lista nueva.

Comment: pero, es decir, si estoy analizando "hola", hay que buscar en cualquier parámetro del otro objeto o solo en la correspondiente al primer objeto.

Comment: Solo en el correspondiente, en el primero en este caso.

Comment: No tengo el codigo de momento... pero intenta con un foreach y dentro de este un if equals arrayA x arrayB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entendí bien, solo es de reconocer el parámetro de un objeto con el parámetro del otro, correspondientemente claro.

Entonces podrías crear variables booleanas para el propósito:

```
   //Verificamos si las posicion de un objeto es igual al otro. Devuelve true si se cumple y false si son diferentes
            boolean posicionIgual = lstA.get(i).getPosicion().equals(lstB.get(i).getPosicion());
            boolean numeroParteIgual = lstA.get(i).getNumeroParte().equals(lstB.get(i).getNumeroParte());
            boolean descripcionIgual = lstA.get(i).getDescripcion().equals(lstB.get(i).getDescripcion());
            boolean montoIgual = lstA.get(i).getMonto() == lstB.get(i).getMonto();
            boolean cambioPrecioIgual = lstA.get(i).getCambioPrecio().equals(lstB.get(i).getCambioPrecio());
            boolean conceptoIgual = lstA.get(i).getConcepto().equals(lstB.get(i).getConcepto());
            boolean montoConvenio = lstA.get(i).getMontoConvenio() == lstB.get(i).getMontoConvenio();
```

Después se podrías crear unas variables para usar como referencia a cada parámetro

```
//Variables donde almacenaremos los valores de cada posicion cada vez que se van encontrando

            //Variables para la lista   lstA
            String primeraPosA = lstA.get(i).getPosicion();
            String segundaPosA = lstA.get(i).getNumeroParte();
            String terceraPosA = lstA.get(i).getDescripcion();
            double cuartaPosA = lstA.get(i).getMonto();
            String quintaPosA = lstA.get(i).getCambioPrecio();
            String sextaPosA = lstA.get(i).getConcepto();
            double septimaPosA = lstA.get(i).getMontoConvenio();

            //Variables para la lista   lstB
            String primeraPosB = lstB.get(i).getPosicion();
            String segundaPosB = lstB.get(i).getNumeroParte();
            String terceraPosB = lstB.get(i).getDescripcion();
            double cuartaPosB = lstB.get(i).getMonto();
            String quintaPosB = lstB.get(i).getCambioPrecio();
            String sextaPosB = lstB.get(i).getConcepto();
            double septimaPosB = lstB.get(i).getMontoConvenio();
```

Con todo lo anterior se procede a comparar mediante if los resultados

```
 if(posicionIgual && numeroParteIgual && descripcionIgual && montoIgual && cambioPrecioIgual && conceptoIgual && montoConvenio){                
                lstC.add(ObjPintura);  //Como no son diferentes da igual poner el ObjPintura1 u ObjPintura2

 }else if(!posicionIgual | !numeroParteIgual | !descripcionIgual | !montoIgual | cambioPrecioIgual | conceptoIgual | montoConvenio){

                //Comienza la búsqueda del parámetro que no cumple y se agrega a la variable que le corresponde

                if(!posicionIgual){

                    primeraPosA = lstA.get(i).getPosicion()+"-";
                    primeraPosB = lstB.get(i).getPosicion()+"+";

                }
                //Se continua comparando con if los siguientes parámetros entrantes con su asignación correspondiente

 //Al finalizar el análisis se procede a llenar la nueva lista con los valores encontrados, tanto repetidos y no repetidos
                lstC.add(new Lista(primeraPosA, segundaPosA, terceraPosA, cuartaPosA, quintaPosA, sextaPosA, septimaPosA));
                lstC.add(new Lista(primeraPosB, segundaPosB, terceraPosB, cuartaPosB, quintaPosB, sextaPosB, septimaPosB));


}
```

Y con un simple for se recorre la nueva lista por consola.

Y con eso compararías parámetros entre objetos. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!